# Visual Code + Intel OpenCL Code Builder

Tags: opencl, intel

is there possibility to have Intel OpenCL SDK including their "Code Builder" plugin to have within Visual Code similarly as MS Visual Studio? If so, please can you link me or advice how to install it for Visual Code?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is no official Code Builder plug-in for VS Code, however you can install vscode-opencl extension, which provides a support for the offline compiler shipped with OpenCL SDK.

Link to Marketplace: [vscode-opencl](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=galarius.vscode-opencl)

Link to GitHub repository: [vscode-opencl](https://github.com/Galarius/vscode-opencl)